# How to get notification from S3 Server Access Loggings to CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I used Terraform to create a new S3 bucket for getting logs automatically from three different existing S3 bucket, next step I want to make the most use of these logs, getting various notification, e.g if someone created/deleted/modified a S3 bucket, relevant users will get notified about the events. Because at the moment all the logs are a mess, and the filename of the logs are all meaningless, I've been messing around with CloudWatch and CloudTrail, not sure what is the right way to do this.Can someone help me, many thanks.

Comment: Did you try this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/log-s3-data-events.html